# Why is calling 'Flush' not sufficient for some apps to see file updates?

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, text

I found this sample code for a async text logger called 'TextLoggerProcessor' online (I cannot remember where) and was experimenting with it in a simple console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int Increment = 100;

        static int LastNumber = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\tracefile.txt"))
            using (var textLoggerProcessor = new TextLoggerProcessor(streamWriter))
            {
                textLoggerProcessor.EnqueueMessage("Doing stuff");

                while (true)
                {
                    var consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

                    if (consoleKeyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                        break;

                    textLoggerProcessor.EnqueueMessage("Doing more stuff");

                    for (int i = LastNumber; i < LastNumber + Increment; i++)
                    {
                        textLoggerProcessor.EnqueueMessage($"Blah ({i})");
                    }

                    LastNumber += Increment;
                }
            }
        }

        public class TextLoggerProcessor : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>(1024);
            private readonly Task _outputTask;

            private TextWriter Output { get; }

            public TextLoggerProcessor(TextWriter textWriter)
            {
                this.Output = textWriter;

                // Start Console message queue processor
                _outputTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    ProcessLogQueue,
                    this,
                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }

            public void EnqueueMessage(string message)
            {
                if (!_messageQueue.IsAddingCompleted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _messageQueue.Add(message);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
                }

                // Adding is completed so just log the message
                this.WriteMessage(message);
            }

            private void WriteMessage(string message)
            {
                this.Output.WriteLine(message);
                this.Output.Flush();
            }

            private void ProcessLogQueue()
            {
                foreach (var message in _messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    this.WriteMessage(message);
                }
            }

            private static void ProcessLogQueue(object state)
            {
                var textLogger = (TextLoggerProcessor)state;

                textLogger.ProcessLogQueue();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _messageQueue.CompleteAdding();

                try
                {
                    _outputTask.Wait();
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
                catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerExceptions.Count == 1 && ex.InnerExceptions[0] is TaskCanceledException) { }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: App built with Visual Studio 2017 using the C# Console app template.

I noticed however that when the file `tracefile.txt` is opened in 'Visual Studio Code' that the updates will not be immediately displayed. The updates will not be displayed until you click into the window. Other apps display similar behavior including 'tail -f' (using Ubuntu through WSL).

However if I use the `Get-Contents -Wait tracefile.txt` command from powershell then the updates will appear immediately; including in 'Visual Studio Code' and by `tail -f`.

Why is `Flush` not sufficient for some apps to see the update? What is the `Get-Contents` command doing differently to cause all the apps to see the updates?

I noticed that opening/closing the file handle for each `Write` will resolve the issue. How much more expensive an operation is it to do this as apposed to calling `Flush`?

Answer (score 0):

At least for 'wsl' (using Ubuntu -18.04) executing 'tail -f ---disable-inotify' works. See https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3292.